# Java String.Split split everyone

Tags: java, android

I want to split a String to Array.

I use the method string.split.

My Code

```
            list = "Toni Mustermann|Jenny Mustermann|Jorge Mustermann";
            kinderarray = list.split("|");
```

But this is the output (Android):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmvT.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHmvT.png]

The Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Wähle ein Kind");
    builder.setItems(kinderarray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            selectkind = kinderarray[item];
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectkind, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression as its argument. The pipe character `|` is a special character used to denote *OR* in the expression. It should be escaped

```
kinderarray = list.split("\\|");
```

otherwise the *OR* expression will cause the `String` to be split into a `String` array based on its individual characters complete with initial empty `String` element.

This has remained the [same for the next year's Java 8 release](http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) so is unlikely to change.

Comment: I hate that they built REs in this way, it's too surprising (Violates the principle of least surprise).  This has probably cost programmer-years in total trying to figure out why something like split("|") doesn't work (albeit a few minutes at a chunk).  I wish they'd just introduced a regular expression type and used something like String.split(new RE("|")) instead.

Comment: Yep, it hasnt changed for Java 8 so I guess its here to stay :/